# Validation not working for dynamically created values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have created a form along with dynamically created form fields (name, age). While trying to validate my age field using javascript, only the first record of the age field is validating - the other ones aren't.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function formValidator(){
     var age = document.getElementById('age');

   if(isNumeric(age, "Please enter a valid Age")){

     return true;

    }
   return false;
     }

    function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
       return true;
      }else{
  alert(helperMsg);
     elem.focus();
 return false;
    }
  }
```

HTML code is:

```
    <html>
      < body>
      <div style="padding-left:70px;"> 
   <input type="button" value="Add Person" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
   <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
   </div>
   </p>
   <table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"  >
   <tbody>
   <tr>
     <p>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td>
    <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" id="name"   >
    </td>
     <td>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age"  >
     </td>

     </p>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="clear"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Only the first field is validating. How can I validate the dynamically generated fields?

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate IDs for form element. which is targeting only first element matched with ID. You should rather use same class and target all of them for validation.

Comment: how to do that any clue ?

Comment: Check the posted answer

Comment: no @ArunPrasanth not working . even not validating for first field all so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs for form element. which is targeting only first element matched with ID. You should rather use same class and target all of them for validation. give class age instead of id and then use:

```
function formValidator(){
var age = document.getElementsByClassName('age');
for (var i = 0; i< age.length; i++) {
   if(!isNumeric(age[i], "Please enter a valid Age")){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: have you modified the DOM. you need to add class age to all age fields.

Comment: i am using class name as array . how can i use it ?

Comment: change `var age = document.getElementsByClassName('age');` to `var age = document.getElementsByClassName('array');`

Comment: ya changed to. document.getElementsByClassName('age[]'); still not working

Comment: @Nayana: can you share the fiddle along with html and js??

Answer (score 0):

If You are using dynamic values then pass dynamic ids to the javascript function and then do the validation

For example :

```
  for(i=0;i<results;i++) 
  {            

    <input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age"<?php echo i; ?>  >

   }
```

And in the javascript function read all the dynamic ids and do the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one element and create it with duplicated ID's. You should get all elements and check them using a loop.

```
function formValidator(){
    var ageEls = document.getElementsByName('age[]'),
        valid = true,
        i = 0;

    while (i < ageEls.length && valid) {
        valid = isNumeric(ageEls[i], "Please enter a valid Age");
        i++;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

JSFiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/3zsLhe9c/3/

Comment: There was a small bug in my script. I've fixed it and create an example on JSFiddler. You have also a syntax error in your HTML code. You can't have a <p> tag between <tr> and <td> tags.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in this line. getElementById returns the DOM element and not its value.

```
var age = document.getElementById('age');
```

To get the value in the DOM element, you should use the 'value' attribute.

```
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
```

hope that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

for jquery i have colustion if you use this "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" js.

```
$("#FrmSubmitToAgent").removeData("validator");
$("#FrmSubmitToAgent").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");$("#FrmSubmitToAgent").removeData("validator");
$("#FrmSubmitToAgent").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```